# Search engine for graphs where we can specify the axis we are looking for

Tags: search-engine, graphs

I am looking for a search engine where I could search for graphs by specifying the axis I am looking for? E.g. axis 1: year; axis 2: price to store 1 TB on a hard drive.

Comment: If anyone has any idea please add an answer.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far.